# how to add ascx inside another ascx and used in sharepoint visual webpart

Tags: web-part

1. I created user control1.ascx and put in controls template folder
2. then add visual webpart in the visual webpart ascx control1.ascx i registered  in visual webpart ascx control and the deployee but sharepoint visual webpart not displaying control1.ascx

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you might need to do the same thing for your inner control that the webpart itself does for its control:

```
// Visual Studio might automatically update this path when you change the Visual Web Part project item.
        private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/ControlInsideControlWebPart/VisualWebPart1/VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx";

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
            Controls.Add(control);
        }
```

But it will be in the Page_Load event of you visual web part user control.

Answer (score 1):

Check your declaration there are should be 3 main parts in the ascx file:

1. Tag registration - `<%@ Register TagPrefix="mycontrol" TagName="simplecontrol" Src="~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/mycontrol.ascx" %>`
2. Reference to assambly which contains code behinde of your control- `<%@ Assembly Name="assemblyname" %>`
3. Control declaration to markup - `<mycontrol:simplecontrolID="simplecontrol" runat="server" />`