# Show hide User Controls in a webpart or switch between webparts

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, visual-web-part, user-controls

How we can achieve below scenario in SharePoint 2013,I am confused where to start:

I have **webpart** which will do login functionality based on list, once user Logged success I need to show a List Items(this will be another **webpart** or User Control). what is the best approach for this?

I'm wondering if I can do this in one webpart which will be having two U**ser controls**  (Login and another as List Item viewer)

Highly appreciate feedback.

thank you.

Comment: Are you using `Visual Web Part` creating Visual Studio?

Comment: than after login just make that control invisible i.e `UserControlID.Visible = false`

Answer (score 1):

Web Part can add another web part or user control on runtime. Here's another [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30743/how-to-add-ascx-inside-another-ascx-and-used-in-sharepoint-visual-webpart) where this was being asked. You just need to modify page Controls collection property on host web part.